# Select List value in loop

Tags: list, loops, ansible

How do I select the value of 'nodeid' or 'managed'. You can copy and paste the code and try.

```
$ cat list.yml
---
- name: Simulate Solarwinds Unmute Nodes
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    SW:
      - results:
         - nodeid: fsd243
         - caption: test1
         - managed : false
      - results:
         - nodeid: ser2
         - caption: ser2cap
         - managed : false

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
    loop: "{{ SW }}"


PLAY [Simulate Solarwinds Unmute Nodes] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'results': [{'nodeid': 'fsd243'}, {'caption': 'test1'}, {'managed': False}]}) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'results': [{'nodeid': 'ser2'}, {'caption': 'ser2cap'}, {'managed': False}]}) => {
    "msg": []
}
```

How do in select the value of 'nodeid' or 'managed'

Answer (score 1):

The value of *results* should be a dictionary

```yaml
    SW:
      - results:
          nodeid: fsd243
          caption: test1
          managed: false
      - results:
          nodeid: ser2
          caption: ser2cap
          managed: false
```

Then, the iteration is trivial

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          nodeid: {{ item.results.nodeid }}
          managed: {{ item.results.managed }}
      loop: "{{ SW }}"
```

---

Q: ***"How do I select the value of 'nodeid' or 'managed'?"***

Given the list of lists

```yaml
    SW:
      - results:
         - nodeid: fsd243
         - caption: test1
         - managed: false
      - results:
         - nodeid: ser2
         - caption: ser2cap
         - managed: false
```

A: Use *json_query*. The result is a list because there might be more items with the same attribute. For example, take the first item

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          nodeid: {{ item.results|json_query('[].nodeid')|first }}
          managed: {{ item.results|json_query('[].managed')|first }}
      loop: "{{ SW }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'results': [{'nodeid': 'fsd243'}, {'caption': 'test1'}, {'managed': False}]}) => 
  msg: |-
    nodeid: fsd243
    managed: False
ok: [localhost] => (item={'results': [{'nodeid': 'ser2'}, {'caption': 'ser2cap'}, {'managed': False}]}) => 
  msg: |-
    nodeid: ser2
    managed: False
```

---

Q: ***"Select only nodeid which is fsd243 and ser2, and managed which is False."***

A: The query below does the job

```yaml
  sw_select: "{{ SW|json_query(sw_query) }}"
  sw_query: '[? !(results.managed) &&
                 (results.nodeid==`fsd243` ||
                  results.nodeid==`ser2`) ]'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    SW:
      - results:
          nodeid: fsd243
          caption: test1
          managed: false
      - results:
          nodeid: ser2
          caption: ser2cap
          managed: true

    sw_select: "{{ SW|json_query(sw_query) }}"
    sw_query: '[? !(results.managed) &&
                   (results.nodeid==`fsd243` ||
                    results.nodeid==`ser2`) ]'

  tasks:
    
    - debug:
        var: sw_select
```